# How can i get a specific widget(i want google review widget) from a side bar?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to use the below code to get a specific review widget in my page but it is not working
`<?php if ( !dynamic_sidebar('Google Review Widget') ) : ?>`

and when i am passing it without an argument it displays all the widgets in the sidebar 
`<?php if ( !dynamic_sidebar('Google Review Widget') ) : ?>`

Comment: you need to format your code properly for people to be able to see it

Answer (score 0):

You code says "If sidebar called 'Google Review Widget' does not exist then..." without anything else.
You are not actually trying to display the sidebar, just check if it exists, and if not then fallback to... nothing.

Simply use: `<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'Google Review Widget' ); ?>` to display it.

Comment: still it displays all the widget present in the sidebar

Answer (score 0):

Displaying only a single Widget from a Sidebar is not an option with standard WP-Functionality. Just register a new sidebar in your funtions.php - See here how to do this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar